# How redirect all request except two folder contents with htaccess angular 4 prod

Tags: php, angular, .htaccess

Hellow, i follow the instrucctions on angular official page to deploy in prod my app, using htaccess that they provide, in this point all fine, but in same server i have webservices in a 2 folders, i need htaccess ignore these specifics uri's and contents

there is the htaccess from angular page

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

and there is the mine

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/webservices/" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/MOAES/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this including in the conditions -f flag to allow archives on that directory

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/webservices/" -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/MOAES/" -f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```